# XSS PHP Log Filter?

Tags: php, regex, xss

I have a log function on my admin panel that checks user input for being correct and, if not correct, writes it to a log file. This log file is written to the admin when logged in.

I was testing my site for vulnerabilities, and I managed to fully exploit my server using an XSS hole. I tried to filter logged input by checking the input through this function:

```
function isXSS($in){
    return preg_match("[<>(%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}+)]", $in) == 1;
}
```

but that would either paranoidly mark everything as a loathed XSS worm, or ignore common XSS injections. I think that the problem is the + quantifier, but I have heard that other PHP regexes allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with good old [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)? I see why you might want to track potentially malicious users, but if you're investing your energy in simply blocking the security holes instead, then there's really no need.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to [enumerate badness](http://www.ranum.com/security/computer_security/editorials/dumb/), which is a battle you'll never win.  Instead, you should be only allowing through markup that you know is good, via a library like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Also, I'm not sure about the `{2}+` syntax, but I believe this is closer to what you want:

```
"[<>(%[0-9a-fA-F]{2,})]"
```